# Issue after changing permalink structure

Tags: htaccess, 404-error

My old permalink structure is like this:

```
domain.com/POSTNAME/
```

My new permalink structure was switched to this:

```
domain.com/CATEGORY/POSTNAME/
```

I need to set up a 301 redirect in htaccess that correctly redirects the old posts. Any help on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to generate the `RewriteRule`s that you will need. Once generated the would go into your `.htaccess` file and need to be prepended with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

The following SQL output should setup rewrite rules for `/postname/` to `/category/postname/` based on what is in your database now. The trailing forward slash is optional.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000; -- make sure we can hold all the redirects
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('RewriteRule ^', post_name, '/?$ ', t.slug, '/', post_name, '/ [R=301,L]') SEPARATOR '\n') redirects
FROM {$wpdb->posts} p 
JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id AND tt.taxonomy = 'category'
JOIN {$wpdb->terms} t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
```

The output will be similar to to following:

```
RewriteRule ^atlanta-falcons/?$ random/atlanta-falcons/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^passion-flower-pistil-negative/?$ photos/passion-flower-pistil-negative/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^crane-takeoff/?$ photos/crane-takeoff/ [R=301,L]
```